# JQuery/CSS/Chrome scrolling bug (viewport drops to end of element when height changes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, debugging

On some of our pages, we've got some legacy JQuery that detects when a page is scrolling and then sets the height of the main element, to position the footer correctly on both mobile and desktop:

```
function scrollPage(event){
  base.keepMainMarginOverFooter();
  // other functions
}
$(window).on('scroll',scrollPage);
```

This is the offending function:

```
keepMainMarginOverFooter:function() {
  // Adjusts container height so footer is clickable but can also be revealed on mobile
  var h = 0;
  $('.fp-section.visible').children().each(function() {
    h+= $(this).outerHeight()
  });
  $('#main').css({ height: h });
}
```

And it seems that there's a bug in Chrome (Version 61.0.3163.100) that seems to trigger if you're actively scrolling during any event which triggers the above code (we also have some JQuery functions that , which automatically takes you to the end of the #main section, ie the bottom of the page. Or at least I guess it's a bug - this doesn't seem to happen in Safari (Version 11.0 12604.1.38.1.7), and it doesn't happen if you wait a couple of seconds after page load before scrolling.

It's tempting to remove this function for something simpler, but it's in the middle of enough dependencies that that wouldn't be trivial.

Is this a known issue with a decent workaround?

Comment: We have found a bug that jQuery in SOME Chromes outerHeight() returns an incorrect value. Only replicated in 2 instances, one windows, on Mac, one "latest", one v49 but all other browsers (including Chrome's on different computers) work fine. Fell back to vanilla JS as it's simpler and correct.